# OAuth and quota with wso2?

Tags: oauth, wso2, quota

We have the following case, we need to allow 3rd party applications to act on behalf of our users (without having their credentials) in order to access our services. Users must first grant access to the 3rd party app and then the 3rd party should never ask again for authorization. We have setup wso2 api manager (we also need quota management), we have exposed one of our services and we had been able to test it. However, we don't just need 3rd party requests just carry a bearer token to access our services. Our objective is to redirect 3rd-party app user to login the first time, grant access to the app and never been asked again.

Is this possible with api manager? should we interface it with wso2 identity server (how?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is the Authorization Code grant type of OAuth 2.0. This capability will be available from WSO2 API Manager 1.4.0 onwards.